Closest edge to a rectangle in a plane of rectangles
I have a 2D plane (with discrete points) that contains arbitrary-sized rectangles and all rectangles are axis aligned. I have their coordinates (upper-left) and sizes (length and breadth).
Suppose I pick a rectangle in this plane and I want to find the closest edge to this rectangle (which also intersects with at least one of the projections of the adjacent side of the rectangle). Here is an example:

My first solution was to check each side of each rectangle one by one and calculate its distance to each side of the given rectangle. But this seems very computationally expensive (especially considering this in a graphical context i.e. every frame of input)
Second was to check if this rectangle is colliding with another (with AABB) if not then by the relative position of their top-left coordinate I can determine which will be the closest edge for this pair.
Can someone propose a better solution to this?
Note 1: You can assume no other rectangles can intersect (with any other) apart from the given rectangle.
EDIT: Thank you @user24714692 and @Clement44 for the answers. I was able to learn a lot from this problem. And I am thankful to you that I was able to build this snap feature in my project:


It seems a lot of tasks to perform.

First, ignore the fact that this is in a 2D plane.
Imagine, we have a line with some points on it.
Solve the "intersection" problem for the line. Let's call this x_axis.
Repeat the same solution for the second y_axis.
We want to find the "intersections" of every two lines with a shared intersection.



Let's imagine you pick one "original" rectangle to compare.
Let's add all the other rectangles in a second group for now.
Note that, the order does not matter. Besides, this is a higher than O(N ^ 2) algorithm, therefore we always sort, both rectangles and intersections.



Once you found the intersections, all you need, is to find the one rectangle with the minimum distance from your "original" rectangle. I'll leave this part to you.

import random


def get_intersections(A, B):
    get_sorted_by_element(A, 1)
    get_sorted_by_element(A, 0)
    get_sorted_by_element(B, 1)
    get_sorted_by_element(B, 0)
    res = []
    a, b = 0, 0
    if A and B:
        while a < len(A) and b < len(B):
            lo = max(A[a][0], B[b][0])
            hi = min(A[a][1], B[b][1])
            if lo <= hi:
                res.append((lo, hi))

            if A[a][1] < B[b][1]:
                a += 1
            else:
                b += 1
    return res


def get_random_rects(n):
    random.seed(1)
    rects = []
    for i in range(n):
        a = c = random.randint(31, 60)
        b = random.randint(70, 90)
        d = random.randint(70, 110)
        rects.append((a, b, c, d))
    return rects


def get_sorted_by_element(A, i):
    return sorted(A, key=lambda x: x[i])


rects_a = get_random_rects(1)
rects_b = get_random_rects(20)
x_axis = get_intersections([(a, b) for a, b, _, _ in rects_a],
                           [(a, b) for a, b, _, _ in rects_b])
y_axis = get_intersections([(c, d) for _, _, c, d in rects_a],
                           [(c, d) for _, _, c, d in rects_b])


print(f"rectangle to compare: {rects_a}")
print(f"other rectangles: {rects_b}")
print(f"x_axis intersections: {x_axis}")
print(f"y_axis intersections: {y_axis}")

x_axis = get_sorted_by_element(x_axis, 0)
y_axis = get_sorted_by_element(y_axis, 1)
print(f"sorted x_axis intersections: {x_axis}")
print(f"sorted y_axis intersections: {y_axis}")

print(x_axis, y_axis)



Prints

rectangle to compare: [(35, 88, 35, 74)] other rectangles: [(35, 88,
35, 74), (39, 73, 39, 101), (55, 84, 55, 100), (51, 82, 51, 83), (34,
85, 34, 71), (59, 82, 59, 97), (50, 70, 50, 98), (39, 77, 39, 107),
(34, 80, 34, 71), (31, 70, 31, 104), (31, 82, 31, 83), (44, 70, 44,
103), (38, 84, 38, 101), (48, 77, 48, 92), (38, 77, 38, 99), (40, 70,
40, 96), (57, 87, 57, 76), (36, 90, 36, 88), (34, 80, 34, 102), (60,
83, 60, 102)] x_axis intersections: [(35, 88), (39, 73), (55, 84),
(51, 82), (35, 85), (59, 82), (50, 70), (39, 77), (35, 80), (35, 70),
(35, 82), (44, 70), (38, 84), (48, 77), (38, 77), (40, 70), (57, 87),
(36, 88)] y_axis intersections: [(35, 74), (39, 74)] sorted x_axis
intersections: [(35, 88), (35, 85), (35, 80), (35, 70), (35, 82), (36,
88), (38, 84), (38, 77), (39, 73), (39, 77), (40, 70), (44, 70), (48,
77), (50, 70), (51, 82), (55, 84), (57, 87), (59, 82)] sorted y_axis
intersections: [(35, 74), (39, 74)] [(35, 88), (35, 85), (35, 80),
(35, 70), (35, 82), (36, 88), (38, 84), (38, 77), (39, 73), (39, 77),
(40, 70), (44, 70), (48, 77), (50, 70), (51, 82), (55, 84), (57, 87),
(59, 82)] [(35, 74), (39, 74)]



We usually define a rectangle with two points, top right and bottom left points.

Here I used three points though:




Note

This problem may look easy at the first glance, but it is a hard question, in my opinion.

What we basically do here, we mirror the rectangles on the x and y axis first.

We find every two lines that have intersections. This technically belongs to those two rectangles. If any two rectangles have intersections, they are in our search space.

Then we have our third or main rectangle to compare with any of these two rectangle. Here we make the comparisons in both Y and X axis and see, our main rectangle is closer to distance, X or Y.




Note

Segment tree is used for range sum:

class SegmentTree:
    def __init__(self, nums):
        self.n = len(nums)
        self.tree = [0] * (2 * self.n)
        self.build(nums)

    def build(self, nums):
        for i in range(self.n):
            self.tree[self.n + i] = nums[i]
        for i in range(self.n - 1, 0, -1):
            self.tree[i] = self.tree[2 * i] + self.tree[2 * i + 1]
        print(self.tree)

    def update(self, idx, val):
        idx += self.n
        self.tree[idx] = val
        while idx > 1:
            idx //= 2
            self.tree[idx] = self.tree[2 * idx] + self.tree[2 * idx + 1]

    def query(self, l, r):
        l += self.n
        r += self.n
        sums = 0
        while l <= r:
            if l % 2 == 1:
                sums += self.tree[l]
                l += 1
            if r % 2 == 0:
                sums += self.tree[r]
                r -= 1
            l //= 2
            r //= 2
        return sums


nums = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
segment_tree = SegmentTree(nums)
queries = [(0, 2), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
for query in queries:
    left, right = query
    result = segment_tree.query(left, right)
    print(result)



Prints
[0, 36, 32, 4, 12, 20, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
9
24
32

Check to see how you can use segment tree for this problem to improve the efficiency? Look at the green lines below.

From Segment Tree
Similarly, check out binary search?

Sorting

Sorting is required. For instance, imagine your two rectangles that you want to check for shared intersections are too far from each other. Therefore, the two rectanlges are not in your search space to be compared with your main rectangle.

Therefore, if you sort, we don't have to check every single rectangle. We only need to check the "near" rectangles, if you will. Those rectangles in the vicinity of each others can only have "intersections".



Thank you for answering! Could you explain what exactly are theses intersections? Intersection of every side (projection of) to every other side? Also, what is a, b, c, d? (x1, y1, x2, y2)? (top-left and bottom-right)

So intersections are the range of points which the original rectangle and other rectangles have in common. So for these rectangles, I calculate their distances in the adjacent axis to compare?

@Harsh That's correct. Technically, we "change" your original problem to a new problem. The new problem also has two subproblems (for Y and X axes).

but wouldn't I still have to loop over the entire array to calculate the distances? What's the point of sorting then? I think I am still missing something here.

Oh I did not notice by sorting you meant the sorting during the intersection calculation. It all makes sense now (still kinda, I still don't get how segment tree are related). Time to implement this!

Lets assume you have two groups of rects with 10^4 elements in each group (bottom left and top right points):
rects_a:[[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [3, 3]], ... and
rects_b[[1000, 1000], [1001, 1001]], [[1002, 1002], [1003, 1003]], ... 
These two groups are far from each other. No comparison in between them are useful. Binary search and segment tree can be used for problems like this.

Can you explain how your intersection algorithm works? As far as I can see you are using AABB to calculate the intersections but something seems to be wrong here.

Thank you for all the guidance! I was able to learn a lot. I was able implement this in my program (see the GIF in edited question).

@Harsh Impressive! You seem to be very talented and have a bright future. My pleasure!

This problem is interesting if you wanted to solve and submit your code.

I will try. At first glance, it seems like a very unique question. You would need to (maybe) selectively use different precision types to minimize the error. But how is indeed the question. (I mean the metaphorical You here)

@Harsh There are three precision types that they look for. There is a zip file with data in the link, you need to take a look and think about it.

I would start by finding the colliding rectangles, and then find the closest one. Here's an algorithm that should work:
array[N,4] # N rectangles, with X coordinate, Y coordinate, width and heigth
distance = inf # Initialize distance with high value    
i = chosenRectangle
closest = 0 # Initialize index of closest rectangle

# Vertical colliding
for j=1,N
    if (i/=j) and (array[j,1] > array[i,1] - array[j,3]) and (array[j,1] < array[i,1] + array[i,3]) then
        evaluate distanceTemp # Distance between rectangles i and j
        if distanceTemp < distance then
            distance = distanceTemp 
            closest = j
        end if
    end if
end for

# Same for horizontal colliding, without reinitialization


Thank you for answering! By distance between rectangles, you mean distance between their closest edge right?

Well I didn't fully understand what distance you wanted to compute. It is the horizontal (respectively vertical) projection of the shortest segment between two horizontally (respectively vertically) colliding rectangles?
Anyway, compute it however you want at this point in the algorithm!
